How to mask 3D tensor efficiently?
Say I have a tensor
import torch
import time
a = torch.rand(2,3,4)

I want to mask it row-wise, so that the top-k values in each row will stay the same, and everything else will be 0.
I have a masking function:
def mask_3D_topk_row_wise(tensor, topk):
    k = int(tensor.shape[-1] * topk)
    k = max(1, k)
    topgetValue, _ = tensor.topk(k, dim=-1)
    mask = tensor >= topgetValue[..., -1].unsqueeze(-1)
    return mask.float()

a = torch.rand(2,3,4)
print(a)
mask_3D_topk_row_wise(a, 0.5)
>>>
tensor([[[0.3811, 0.8600, 0.5645, 0.1745],
         [0.3302, 0.4977, 0.7563, 0.1393],
         [0.3316, 0.4179, 0.5782, 0.5872]],

        [[0.4027, 0.4618, 0.7154, 0.8319],
         [0.0310, 0.8549, 0.7839, 0.7191],
         [0.2406, 0.2045, 0.3236, 0.3338]]])
tensor([[[0., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1., 1.]],

        [[0., 0., 1., 1.],
         [0., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1., 1.]]])

The issue is that this is very slow for large tensors, which I have to run many times:
tensor = torch.rand(1000, 1024, 1024)  # create a sample tensor
topk = 0.5

start_time = time.time()
original_mask = mask_3D_topk_row_wise(tensor, topk)
end_time = time.time()
print(f"function took {end_time - start_time:.4f} seconds")
>>> function took 3.5493 seconds

Is there a more efficient way to create such mask?
